# PyMC to PyMC3 for bayesian statistics model

Tags: python, pymc3, pymc

I am starting on Bayesian Statistics using the book Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers. I realized that the code examples there are based on pymc which has been deprecated in favor of pymc3. I am trying to figure out how to port the code into pymc3 code, but am running into issues there.
I was wondering if someone could help port the following code snippet to pymc3:

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm

count_data = np.loadtxt("txtdata.csv")
n_count_data = len(count_data)

alpha = 1.0 / count_data.mean()

lambda_1 = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha)
lambda_2 = pm.Exponential("lambda_2", alpha)

tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data)

@pm.deterministic
def lambda_(tau=tau, lambda_1=lambda_1, lambda_2=lambda_2):
    out = np.zeros(n_count_data)
    out[:tau] = lambda_1  # lambda before tau is lambda1
    out[tau:] = lambda_2  # lambda after (and including) tau is lambda2
    return out

observation = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, value=count_data, observed=True)

model = pm.Model([observation, lambda_1, lambda_2, tau])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(40000, 10000, 1)
lambda_1_samples = mcmc.trace('lambda_1')[:]
lambda_2_samples = mcmc.trace('lambda_2')[:]
tau_samples = mcmc.trace('tau')[:]
```

I was able to do it partially, but then I am running into trouble at the line

```
@pm.deterministic
```

My partial code (for what it is worth):

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

count_data = np.loadtxt("txtdata.csv")
n_count_data = len(count_data)

alpha = 1.0 / count_data.mean()

basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:
    lambda_1 = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha)
    lambda_2 = pm.Exponential("lambda_2", alpha)
    tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data)

    @pm.deterministics
    def lambda_(tau=tau, lambda_1=lambda_1, lambda_2=lambda_2):
        out = np.zeros(n_count_data)
        out[:tau] = lambda_1  # lambda before tau is lambda1
        out[tau:] = lambda_2  # lambda after (and including) tau is lambda2
        return out

    observation = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, value=count_data, observed=True)
```

How do I get this to work in pymc3?

Comment: It's already all ported: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers